# Decode Xml to mxGraph .Net

Tags: mxgraph

I want to execute an operation that is an inversion of what i do when forming xmlString in mxGraph().

```
mxGraph graph = new mxGraph();
        Object parent = graph.GetDefaultParent();

        graph.Model.BeginUpdate();
        try
        {
            Object v1 = graph.InsertVertex(parent, null, "Hello,", 20, 20, 80, 30);
            Object v2 = graph.InsertVertex(parent, null, "World!", 200, 150, 80, 30);
            Object e1 = graph.InsertEdge(parent, null, "Edge", v1, v2);
        }
        finally
        {
            graph.Model.EndUpdate();
        }

        mxCodec codec = new mxCodec();
        Xml = mxUtils.GetXml(codec.Encode(graph.Model));
        var xmlString = mxUtils.GetXml(xml);
```

I'm trying to execute inverse operation.

```
        XmlDocument doc = mxUtils.ParseXml(xmlString);

        mxGraph graphNew = new mxGraph();

        var decoder = new mxCodec(doc);



        decoder.Decode(doc, graphNew.Model);

        Object parentNew = graphNew.GetDefaultParent();
```

But the object "parentNew" has no children.

Answer (score 1):

this code:

```
decoder.Decode(doc, graphNew.Model);
```

should be replaced with this code below:

```
decoder.Decode(doc.DocumentElement, graphNew.Model);
```

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this myself and was able to solve it.

```
decoder.Decode(doc, graphNew.Model);
```

should be:

```
decoder.Decode(doc.DocumentElement, graphNew.getModel());
```

In addition to `doc.DocumentElement`, you also need to use `graphNew.getModel()`, not just `graphNew.model`.

As per this [documentation](https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/docs/js-api/files/io/mxCodec-js.html)

Also, you do not need to create a new graph. Insert your existing graph into the second parameter of `Decode`.